# Magento 2 - Difference between Model, ResourceModel. Collection and Repository

Tags: magento2, model, service-contract

I'm studying Magento and I'm confusing about the differences between these four layers. What I have understood is the following:

**Model**

Is the entity class with ONLY getters/setters and magic methods.

**ResourceModel**

Is the layer responsible of C.R.U.D operations. This class should contains ONLY the `_construct` method to map my entity with the database table.

**Collection**

As the name suggested, it's a class that implements IterableInterface and give me only a list of Entity.

**Repository**

It's a class that expose API methods to the external and it's also used to execute operations to database. It's used to save/load/delete entity (internally I think that for these CRUD operations it should use the ResourceModel) and to expose methods to get collections of results.

***EntityName*Interface**

It's the interface that Model should implement.

***EntityName*RepositoryInterface**

It's the interface that Repository should implement.

But not all Magento modules work in this way, so there are modules that don't use this approach yet, but for compatibility reasons they use the old approach. Is it correct what I learned to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Models :-**

Models are where your main **business logic** should be handled and is a **single instance of an object**.

The model will use the `resource model` to talk to the `database` and **get/set** data for it on `save()` and `load()`.

> **Resource Model :**

A resource model is where your main **C.R.U.D** happens `(Create, Read, Update and delete)`.

The resource model shouldn’t contain business **logic** however it will talk to the `adapters` and basically talk to the `database`.

> **Collections :**

During development, if working with `collections` that have lot of `attributes`, `filters`, and possibly a future `large dataset`, we might want to use `SQL logging` to record actual `SQL queries hitting` the database server.

This might help us spot possible performance `bottlenecks` and react on time, either by adding more limiting values to **setPageSize** or **addAttributeToSelect** , or both.

> **Repositories :**

when you use repositories you adhere to `Magento 2` service `contracts`, which means that `service interfaces` and `data interfaces` are defined **(but extensible by third-party modules)**.

Making it possible at **run-time** to change the result of the call to the `getList()` method of a **repository** would violate this contract.
To retrieve the `attributes` you need at run-time you can use collections.

**Magento 2 framework** itself makes an heavy use of `collections`.
Otherwise you should implement a module which defines a new data interface **(that is, the new set of attributes)** for that entity.

Comment: So, for example, if I need to create a function that give me all products recommended (for recommended I mean the products that belong to same category), I should extend the ProductRepository or the ProductResourceModel? I think that to adhere to Magento 2 service contracts, the right place to add this type of function is inside a class that extends ProductRepository

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

Models are where your main business logic should be handled and we can get or set one row of entity by using Model. Model will call the resource model to get or set entity in database.

**Resource Model**

CRUD operations are handled in resource model but it don't have a business logic.

**Collections**

Collection have lot of attributes and filters. It has a whole entity of data. Using filter method, we can filter specified data from database table.

Answer (score 0):

Models : Models are where your main business logic should be handled and is a single instance of an object. The model will use the resource model to talk to the database and get/set data for it on save() and load().

Resource Model : A resource model is where your main C.R.U.D happens (Create, Read, Update and delete). The resource model shouldn’t contain business logic however it will talk to the adapters and basically talk to the database.